# Theme for devexpress ribbon control in WPF

Tags: wpf, themes, devexpress, ribbon

How to set theme for devexpress ribbon control in WPF? Already installed the WPF theme editor, but there is no item in the product browser to select. I tried property ribbon style, but it does not work either.

Comment: Have you tried contacting devexpress instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main window should start with <dx:ThemedWindow > tag.

- Add theme references to project by context menu on the references section, DLL names start with DevExpress.Xpf.Themes. ...
- Click on smart tag button for the form.
- Select application theme from the combobox.
  p.s: this solution applies to .net 4.7 or equivalent